# javascript regexp for numbers between 00-59 (seconds)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a field is a valid time value (just seconds). So I want to accept the numbers from 0 to 59. I came out with this:

```
[0-5][0-9]?
```

which almost does the job. But excludes the digits 7-8-9... It works if the user digit 07, but I don't want to force the user to digit the first 0. So I tried something like this:

```
([0-5][0-9]? | [0-9])
```

but this does not works and produces an error of too many recursive calls.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it have to be a regex??

Comment: Don't think you need the ? in the second expression, since you already cover that case in the second optional part.

Comment: Honestly, I would just parse the value as a base-10 number and compare it to `0` and `59`. A regex seems overkill here.

Comment: "*too many recursive calls*" - huh, what? A regex (at least a JS one) cannot be recursive. What do you mean?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi mmm I could. But in that case I would have to remove the last digit if input >59. Because the single '8' it's fine. But '82' no, and in such case I have to remove the '2'.

I just thought that a regexp would have been more elegant

Comment: @Segolas, so when the value is greater than `59`, you want to keep the first digit and ignore the second one? Don't you think this will confuse your users? Arguably, a value like `82` should be rejected, not interpreted as `8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your 2nd regex, you need to remove that `?` from the first part, and make it `[1-5]` instead of `[0-5]`:

```
[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]
```

And if you want to be flexible enough to allow both `7` and `07`, then use `[0-5]`:

```
[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]
```

And then, simplifying the above regex, you can use:

```
[0-5]?[0-9]   // ? makes [0-5] part optional
```

Comment: Wouldn't [0-9]|[0-5][0-9] be even better.

Comment: @Armin. I thought OP didn't wanted to enter `07`.

Comment: Nope. I tried your code in here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and it matches also 88

Comment: @Segolas. Did you try the last one? Actually in 1st regex, you need to group the 2nd part, which I forgot. So, use `[0-9]|([0-5][0-9])`. Or even better use the last one.

Comment: @RohitJain yes. I tryed that one http://i.imgur.com/PCtRtDO.png

Also I obtain a match with the [0-9]|[0-5][0-9]

Comment: @Segolas. Ah! You didn't add anchors there. Use `^[0-5]?[0-9]$` to match at the start and end of the strign.

Comment: @RohitJain perfect! Thanks. I suck with the regexp (maybe because I'ma little dyslessic?)

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient: `[0-5]?\d`

However if you want to enforce two digits (ie. `01`, `02`...) you should just use `[0-5]\d`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the tens digit optional, not the unit position, place the `?` there:

```
[0-5]?[0-9]
```

Comment: @Juan, technically, [decade](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decade) can mean "group of ten", not only "period of ten years" (it's also the usual translation for the French *dizaine*, which means "group of ten"). In this case, Bergi was referring to groups of ten seconds.

Comment: @Juan: The second digit from the right. Likely it was a wrong or uncommon translation, not sure whether there's a better expression

Comment: @Bergi, I kind of guessed that, but I looked it up and didn't see decade defined as the tens digit, just wanted to find out whether it was common usage or not. Wikipedia doesn't list it but http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decade does

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 0 to be optional, move the `?` to just after the `[0-5]` instead.

`[0-5]?[0-9]` should do it.

Comment: unable to put 6,7,8,9 in this case.